# What is "Fischers" in Fischers Fritz?

Tags: genitive, person-names

I learned the following [*Zungenbrecher*](https://www.goethe.de/resources/files/pdf24/pk10302680.pdf).

> Fischers Fritz fischt frische Fische. Frische Fische fischt Fischers Fritz

I understand this means "A man named Fritz fishes fresh fish", repeated in different word orders.

My question is: what is *Fischers* here? I stumbled on [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/German/comments/otu7ss/fischers_fritz_fischt_frische_fische_frische/), but still not clear about what the default understanding of native speakers is. Is  it the case that *Fischers Fritz* as a whole is a name? Or is it an instance of [Sächsischer Genitiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A4chsischer_Genitiv), or even something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A somewhat odd and old way to tell the last name of a person is (or was) to add an 's' to their family name and make it a possesive.
In this case, it is **Fritz Fischer** who is called "**Fischers Fritz**"

As families more often get called like that, it is not very common for an individual person.

Example:

*Unsere Nachbarn, die Fischers, sind schon wieder im Urlaub.*

This means "*Familie Fischer*" in this context.

And this is where **Fischers** in your question originates:
*Fischers Fritz ist schon wieder im Urlaub*

Comment: Given that Fritz is actually fishing I always interpreted him more literally to be the fisherman’s son. But what you write is of course absolutely valid. Especially since “Fischer” is used without an article.

Comment: @CarstenS: yes, good point, that's the origin of family names in general. I am not sure but "Fischers Fritz" is that old that it would be plausible to argue your way. But since I also heard this usage often in modern german, I think it is an understandable explanation.

Comment: Thank you. As a follow-up, when you say *old*, do you mean it's completely outdated to use *SURNAME+s FIRSTNAME* now? Or can Max Braun be denoted by *Brauns Max* in some cases (if uncommon)?

Comment: @sundowner: no, it is not completely outdated. it is of "old origin" and not commonly used, but usually understood by adults. I think most adult people will get you mean "Max Braun" when talking about "Brauns Max". Most Children will not. I do not have data/confidence here, it is just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

First off: the sentences main purpose is not really to make much sense but rather constructed to make you train your speaking apparatus. In German this is called a "Zungenbrecher" (tongue twister, verbatim: "tongue breaker") as you have already found out. The sentence is supposed to be spoken fast while still clear. It is difficult to change between "-f-" and "-fr-" and most people produce something like *Frischers Fitz ...* on their first tries.

For the sentence itself, historically fishing was a small business which usually was owned by the oldest male and consisted of all the family members with the occasional apprentice from outside thrown in for good measure. So "Fischers Fritz" is most likely the son of the business owner (the fisher himself) or, less likely, his apprentice or his menial. In any case, the name of the son/apprentice/menial is "Fritz", a short form of "Fried(e)rich".

Quite often (but not always) people were so closely identified with their jobs that at some point their profession became their (last) name. Here, "Fischer" (fisherman) is likely a profession but it could well be that the mentioned fisherman also is named *Some_Surname* Fischer. This is the origin of names like "Fischer", "Bäcker" (baker), "Meier, Maier, Meyer, ..." ("Meierei" is a dairy farm), "Schulze" (approx. "Sheriff"), "Müller" (miller), "Bauer" (farmer) and so on.

That leaves the question why "Fischers" and not "des Fischers". The *Genitiv* is a clearly marked case and therefore the *Artikel* is not necessary. It is used only if there is one thing or person in question, so "Fischers Fritz" only makes sense if there is just one Fischer. The device is mostly used in poetic language, poems especially. Here are lyrics as an example:

> Über Liebchens Dache
> Glänzt ein heller Stern,
> Venus hält dort Wache,
> Schützt die Holde gern.
> ....
> (Otto Franz Gensichen, quoted after [www.lieder.net](https://www.lieder.net/get_text.html?TextId=91326))

Obviously there is only one "Liebchen" (love interest).

Comment: I like your elaboration of the last name origins, but I think "Liebchen" in "Liebchens Dache" is a true genitive and therefore the example does not help here. This is for "Fischers Fritz" describes Fritz belonging to a family, even though a person cannot be owned.

Comment: Of course it is a "true genitive" - like "Fischer**s**" is. "Fischers Fritz" *could* be the son of a person (usually man) named Fischer, of the profession fisher or it could be the apprentice or menial of one of these.